# Field contains or is equal to another field

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to write a query to return results where "Column B" is equal to or contains "Column A".

I need both, because some fields in Column B are an exact match for field in Column A, and sometimes the value in Column B is the value from Column A with additional characters added on the end.

| Example | Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1234 | 12345abc |
| 2 | abcde | abcde |

I have tried:

```sql
TableName.[Column B] like TableName.[Column A]    -- this only returns exact matches
TableName.[Column B] like 'TableName.[Column A]%' -- this returns nothing
TableName.[Column B] = 'TableName.[Column A]%'    -- this returns nothing
```

Any assistance would be incredible, thanks!

Comment: What about `TableName.[Column B] like '%'+TableName.[Column A]+'%'`?

Comment: @Rafalon Hi, thanks for replying. This returns rows where Column B matches Column A, but excludes contains

Comment: This is not what [this SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d3e03/1/0) shows

Comment: @Rafalon apologies, you are right. I had the columns the wrong way around. Thank you vey much for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Rafalon is correct. Use:

```
TableName.[Column B] like '%' + TableName.[Column A] + '%'
```

When you add the wildcards, you have to make them a string but the `TableName.[Column A]` cannot be a string. The above code will include all instances of B that contains A. When you ask for an exact match, the same code will do that because when they match exactly, of course B will contain A.